# Aggregating and plotting multiple columns using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got data in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID    A    B    C    D
100   0    1    0    1
101   1    1    0    1
102   0    0    0    1
...
```

The idea is to create a barchart plot that shows the total of each (sum of the total number of A's, B's, etc.).  Something like:

```
      X 
  X   X
x X   X 
A B C D
```

This should be so simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set 'ID' aside, [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), and [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.set_index('ID').sum().plot.bar()

# or
df.drop(columns=['ID']).sum().plot.bar()
```

output:

[image]

##### just for fun

```
print(df.drop(columns='ID')
        .replace({0: ' ', 1: 'X'})
        .apply(sorted, reverse=True)
        .to_string(index=False)
     )
```

Output:

```
A B C D
X X   X
  X   X
      X
```